# tkinter: Label to extend end to end of a frame question

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a console that has a single Label packing into a frame. I'm using pack and not grid or place.

Currently the label is placed into the frame, and is configured to expand. However the expansion doesn't stretch to expand to every edge. Also, when the window is resized, the Label widget doesn't resize together with the frame.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import time as t


class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self,bg="black")
        self.frame=tk.Canvas(self.canvas,bg="black")
        self.scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.title("label insert and scrollbar test")
        self.geometry("900x400")

        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.X,expand=1)
        self.frame.pack(fill=tk.X,expand=1)

        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),anchor='n',window=self.frame)
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>",self.onFrameConfigure)

    def onFrameConfigure(self,event):
        pass

    def run(self):
        ntime=t.asctime(t.gmtime())
        n=tk.Label(self.frame,text=ntime,anchor="nw",justify=tk.LEFT)
        n.config(bg="black",fg="white",font=("Courier",12))
        n.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1,padx=0)
        self.after(800,self.run)

if __name__=="__main__":
    m=app()
    m.run()
    m.mainloop()
```

How do i get this to work such that the Label fills the entire frame?

Comment: A couple of questions. Do you have something against `grid()` and why are you using a canvas for this? You are not placing anything on a frame. You are placing things on a canvas.

Comment: No i don't but i was wondering why pack wasn't able to do this? isn't n=tk.Label(self.frame, ... ) putting the label in the frame?

Comment: Pack can do this but you stated you were using `pack()` and not `grid()` and I wanted to know if you didnt understand something about grid. That said you are close. There is a couple of things you need to change.

Comment: And those changes would be ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reason why your frame is not expanding to fit the canvas. You have a few issues that we need to correct first.

1. `self.frame=tk.Canvas(self.canvas,bg="black")` is not actually a frame.
2. `onFrameConfigure` is not doing anything and this is an important part to getting the frame to resize.
3. `self.frame.bind()` should be `self.canvas.bind()` as we are using the even that the canvas has changed in some way to trigger the function to resize the frame.
4. `self.canvas.create_window((0,0),anchor='n',window=self.frame)` needs a tag set for the frame so we can configure it in the function later.

See below code example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as t


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg="black")
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.title("label insert and scrollbar test")
        self.geometry("900x400")

        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
        self.frame.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), anchor='n', window=self.frame, tags='my_frame')
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.run()

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(my_frame, width=width)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def run(self):
        ntime = t.asctime(t.gmtime())
        n = tk.Label(self.frame, text=ntime, anchor="nw", justify='left')
        n.config(bg="black", fg="white", font=("Courier", 12))
        n.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0)
        self.after(800, self.run)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Update:

The below example changes some background colors and padding so you can see where exactly things are expanding.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as t


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, bg='darkblue',)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.title("label insert and scrollbar test")
        self.geometry("900x400")

        self.scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), anchor='n', window=self.frame, tags='my_frame')
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)
        self.run()

    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure("my_frame", width=event.width, height=event.height)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def run(self):
        ntime = t.asctime(t.gmtime())
        tk.Label(self.frame, bg='black', fg='white', text=ntime,
                 font=("Courier", 12)).pack(fill='both', expand=True , padx=5, pady=5)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
        self.after(800, self.run)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Example results:

[image]

Comment: @placidchat sorry I had to fix the tag name in the code. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes you are right about the mistakes, i was typing it out from the original program. The original onframeconfigure has a few commands for setting the scrollbar to follow the text in the Label, and was omitted for clarity. But the answer doesn't expand the label to fit the x and y direction. There's a blank space on N,S of the the Label. I'm trying to make it look like a terminal.

Comment: @placidchat you want the label to expand vertically as well?

Comment: yes, i want it to look like a terminal session. I had thought putting the Label would have anchored it to the nw and expand=true,fill=tk.BOTH would have expanded everything to both edges.

Comment: @placidchat it will but your frame also has to expand correctly. To do that you have to force the frame to resize on canvas config.

Comment: How would you do that? Also the Label size seems to be set to a certain size in the beginning, and is not able to cover the entire frame in black.

Comment: I added padding so you can see that the labels were in fact expanding. That said if you want the entire screen to be black then you need to have the canvas fill both.

Comment: Yes but Label wouldn't automatically expand to fill the top and bottom. The end goal is to have behave like a terminal, and the label configuration doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Also i found doing this in the original code:      self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure), didn't work because the Label parent was a frame, so self.frame.bind worked instead

Comment: @placidchat You need to bind on canvas config in order to resize the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my question:
'''
self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
self.frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1,padx=1)
'''

Would expand both canvas and frame to fit the entire window. The original code only had fill=tk.X, which expands only in the X direction. For some reason i could have sworn the documentation said tk.X meant in both directions.